# Parsing string using regex

Tags: regex, regex-group

Hello regex gurus: Need help parsing the ABC_ID from string below. It may or may not be present in all strings.

Input String:

{"ABC_ID":"b2cf780101d63444e146043a3da498d9b674893f3bcf3d82bd186e6fc7c51b67","XYZ_ID":"xx.ab.jkirskd.gt-{comp}-en.bell&kwesrd=ZzZz.47876740995._hoo_clickid_.sitelink"}

Output required: b2cf780101d63444e146043a3da498d9b674893f3bcf3d82bd186e6fc7c51b67

Comment: Why not use a json parser?

Comment: Please explain the logic. Is it "the string within double quotes, following a ':'  after 'ABC_ID' in double quotes? That would require the guarantee that the desired result never contains double quotes. Is there any guarantee about the length of the desired string? Is it guaranteed to be lowercase hexdigits only? And finally, what are your own attempts? Do not forget that you are expected to demonstrate some own research effort.

Comment: Taking the [tour] and reading [ask] might provide you with some insights into how StackOverflow is meant to be used.

Comment: What regex flavor are you using? You can answer this by naming the tool or language you use.

Answer (score 0):

this regex `\{"ABC_ID":"([^"]*)"`
is matching, for example

{"ABC_ID":"**b2cf780101d63444e146043a3da498d9b674893f3bcf3d82bd186e6fc7c51b67**","XYZ_ID":"xx.ab.jkirskd.gt-{comp}-en.bell&kwesrd=ZzZz.47876740995._hoo_clickid_.sitelink"}

and saves the value in variable $1

### Screenshot of this working example inside a Jetbrains-Editor:

[image]